# It seems to me as if std::getline doesn't handle new lines correctly?

Tags: c++, getline

With the code below, I want the user to write a text in the terminal, and then print out the last sentence of the text. Maybe I should mention that I'm running on a Linux desktop.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream> 

int main()
{
    std::string user_text{};

    while(std::getline(std::cin, user_text))
    {

    }

    std::cout << "Text: " << user_text << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Anyways if I, after running the program, write for example:

> Hi my name is

And then press 'ctrl+d', the output will indeed be `"Text: Hi my name is"`

However if I instead do this:

> Hi my name is 'press enter'
>
> Name my is hi 'press enter'

And then press 'ctrl+d'. The output will be `"Text: "`. Why is this? Shouldn't getline stop when I have pressed 'ctrl+d'?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first time you terminate the input after writing a complete line. The second time you terminate input right after pressing enter, i.e. after reading an _empty line_.

Comment: Clearer: The second example has _three_ lines, two of which have text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::getline()` erases the output `std::string` before attempting to read from the stream.

In your second case, the first 2 calls to `std::getline()` have already read everything you have typed in, there is nothing left when you press <kbd>CTRL-D</kbd> during the 3rd call, so there is nothing for `std::getline()` to output into the `std::string`.

Save the last successful line read to a separate variable, eg:

```cpp
std::string user_text, line;

while(std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    user_text = line;
}

std::cout << "Text: " << user_text << std::endl;
```

Comment: Not sure about this answer, the documentation on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) is not completely clear, but [when I try it out, it does not seem to clear the string when the read fails](https://godbolt.org/z/5z4csYd7T).

Comment: My understanding is that `std::getline` gets everything until the next `\n` or end-of-file (That's not a character!). Thus it returns the empty line he already started.

Comment: @asynts "*After constructing and checking the sentry object, performs the following:
1) Calls `str.erase()`*" - seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: That's why I am confused, because it doesn't do that. In [the example](https://godbolt.org/z/5z4csYd7T), after the second call (which fails) `value` is still `foo`.

Comment: @asynts your example does not take into account that the 2nd `value` might be evaluated before the 2nd `getline()` is executed.  Put a `;` between `getline()` and `<< value` and see what happens

Comment: [Nope, that's not it.](https://godbolt.org/z/TMe6751hW)

Comment: You are right about the evaluation order though, it's undefined behavior to access `value` when it is modified by `std::getline` without a sequence point. [This example should be without undefined behaviour.](https://godbolt.org/z/EGjvMTT6h)

Comment: @asynts then godbolt's implementation of `getline()` is not conforming to documented behavior.

Comment: Actually, the standard (or rather this unofficial draft) says that [`str.erase()` is called if `sentry` converts to `true`](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.io#6) which happens if `std::cin.good()` returns `true` which may, or may not be the case. My understanding is, that depending on the implementation, the end-of-file bit could be set, thus `str.erase()` could be called.

Answer (score 1):

`std::getline` is working as intended: it's getting a line. If you press enter, it creates a new, empty line; if you then press ctrl+d, you're terminating std::getline, which returns that (empty) line's contents.

From the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

> getline reads characters from an input stream and places them into a string:
>
> 1. Behaves as UnformattedInputFunction, except that input.gcount() is not affected. After constructing and checking the sentry object, performs the following:
>
>    1. Calls str.erase()
>    2. Extracts characters from input and appends them to str until one of the following occurs (checked in the order listed)
>       a) end-of-file condition on input, in which case, getline sets eofbit.
>       b) the next available input character is delim, as tested by Traits::eq(c, delim), in which case the delimiter character is extracted from input, but is not appended to str.
>       c) str.max_size() characters have been stored, in which case getline sets failbit and returns.
>    3. If no characters were extracted for whatever reason (not even the discarded delimiter), getline sets failbit and returns.
> 2. Same as getline(input, str, input.widen('\n')), that is, the default delimiter is the endline character.

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl+D` causes the process's `read` from the terminal to return immediately. If you press `Ctrl+D` after typing: `Hi my name is`, the process will read: `Hi my name is`. `getline` will not find a `\n` and will restart reading. Then you press `Ctrl+D` a second time (you didn't say it but I am sure you did). And this will interrupt the `read`, causing it to return 0, which is as-if the terminal was closed. `getline` will then return the current value: `Hi my name is`.

In the second case, you haven't typed anything since the last `\n`, so when you press `Ctrl+D`, `read` directly returns 0 and `getline` returns with an empty string.

Comment: I didn't say the process was terminated. I say the process's `read` returned immediately.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110240/why-does-ctrl-d-eof-exit-the-shell

Comment: It will read `until` it reaches EOF or \n. In this case the first call to read will stop after `Hi my name is` because Ctrl+D will interrupt it. As there is no EOF or '\n' getline will keep reading.

Comment: What would you like to see ?